# Twilio messaging request not getting to nginx when SSL is implemented

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, twilio

We recently implemented SSL on our nginx server.  Changing the messaging request url for my twilio number from `http://mywebsite.com` to `https://www.mywebsite.com` causes the request to the new url to not show up in nginx's logs.  The same request through curl works fine.

There are no redirects involved with the twilio request.

The curl request that simulates that request is:

```
curl -X GET "https://www.mywebsite.com/twilio_receiver?ToCountry=US&ToState=VA&SmsMessageSid=XXXXX&NumMedia=0&ToCity=FREDERICKSBG&FromZip=22407&SmsSid=XXXXX&FromState=VA&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=FREDERICKSBG&Body=Whit&FromCountry=US&To=%2B11111111111&ToZip=22407&MessageSid=XXXXX&AccountSid=XXXXX&From=%2B11111111111&ApiVersion=2010-04-01"
```

...which is logged by nginx as:

```
68.98.147.198 - - [10/Jul/2014:21:24:23 +0000] "GET /twilio_receiver?ToCountry=US&ToState=VA&SmsMessageSid=XXXXX&NumMedia=0&ToCity=FREDERICKSBG&FromZip=22407&SmsSid=XXXXX&FromState=VA&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=FREDERICKSBG&Body=Whit&FromCountry=US&To=%2B11111111111&ToZip=22407&MessageSid=XXXXX&AccountSid=XXXXX&From=%2B111111111111&ApiVersion=2010-04-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 1266 "-" "curl/7.32.0"
```

My nginx config file looks like (the {{ XXX }} things are ansible variables, but they get expanded on the server):

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:{{ project_root }}/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

# this server block redirects naked domains to www.*
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name mywebsite.com;
  return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}

# this server block redirects http requests to https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mywebsite.com;
  return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl spdy default_server ipv6only=on;

  root {{ project_root }}/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www_mywebsite_com.chained;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www_mywebsite_com.key;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

try_files $uri/maintenance.html $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

location @unicorn {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect   off;
  proxy_pass       http://unicorn;
}

location ~ ^/(assets)/ {  
  gzip_static on;
  expires     max;
  add_header  Cache-Control public;
}

location ~ ^/(sidekiq)/ {
  try_files $uri @unicorn;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
  expires       max;
  add_header    Cache-Control public;
  log_not_found off;
  access_log    off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
  allow         all;
  log_not_found off;
  access_log    off;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
  expires       max;
  log_not_found off;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 10;   
}
```

I have tried disabling the firewall completely; no effect.  The server is running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Is the target URL using a certificate that is chained to a globally-trusted root CA? If not, the HTTPS connection from Twilo to you will likely fail due to a certificate error.

Comment: EricLaw - yes it's a chained certificate.  I've solved this problem now, adding an answer below.

Comment: jww - You are perhaps right, but this question is similar in character to many of the 9000+ nginx questions on stackoverflow.  Interestingly, there are only 61 nginx questions on Webmaster Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Twilio uses SSLv3, so this needs to be added to the ssl_protocols line in the nginx config above, like so:

```
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

This is in fact the default in later versions of nginx, so just not including the ssl_protocols line at all is also an option!

Comment: For anyone who may be searching later, I've been speaking with the Twilio support team and they've confirmed that, "Regarding cryptographic protocols, Twilio supports the TLS cryptographic protocol. Support for SSLv3 is officially deprecated."